# Javascript Array Access undefined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am totally new to javascript, but I can program in Java, C# etc. already.

I want to generate a card deck, and after that I want to access this array of cards.

```
function Card(rank, suit)
{
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}

function Deck()
{
    this.ranks = new Array("A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K");
    this.suits = new Array("Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades");
    this.cards = Array(52);
    this.makeDeck = function()
    {
        console.log("Executed MakeDeck!");
        for(var i = 0; i < this.suits.length; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0; j < this.ranks.length; j++)
            {
                this.cards.push(new Card(this.ranks[j],this.suits[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}

function btnClick()
{
    var deck = new Deck();
    deck.makeDeck();
    console.log(deck.cards[0]);
}
```

In the function "btnClick()" I want to log the first item in the array, but the console just tells my "undefined". I can't find my mistake, maybe you can help me?

Comment: -hisses like a cat- Don't use `new Array()`! Use array literals: `["A","2",...];`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Does it really matter?

Comment: @Phil In this case it's the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Juhana Ah, too true! I didn't realise the internal pointer was positioned at the end of the array when using the *length* constructor

Comment: Bioaim - Learn to use your browser's debugging tool. This will help you identify problems like this in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have initialised an array with 52 elements... and you are then `push`ing *more* elements onto it.

What you need to do is just have `this.cards = [];`. JavaScript has variable-length arrays.

Comment: "JavaScript has variable-length arrays." <-- very important distinction

Comment: Not 52 elements actually. Just a `.length` of 52, it's a *sparse* array.

Comment: thank you very much, it works now.. but i don't push more then 52 elements in the array. its length is actually 52.